# Looking up specific value in KTable

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Kafka topic.
I have a stream  with the key being a stock symbol and the Value being a Hi/Low pojo. I also have a KTable that captures the current state of the stream.

I want to process every record in the stream one by one. For each record, I want to look up the current value of that symbol from a KTable. Then depending on whether the Hi/Low changes, I want to update the KTable and then write the message to the stream.

Comment: The JavaDoc shows how to query a KTable via the Interactive Queries feature. https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KTable.html

Comment: I don't think that interactive queries help for this use case. However, overall it seems that you would need to use the Processor API and not the DSL to get more flexibility. In you custom Processor you can use a KeyValueStore (what is effectively the same as a KTable) and write custom logic to do the lookups and updates.